# Printing a continuous BufferedImage

Tags: java, printing

I am trying to print a continuous buffered image onto seperate pages. The problem I have is that the best I can do is print the last page. The count on the variable inty seems to be ignored until it reaches the end.
Here is my code

```
public class PrintDocs implements Printable {
    BufferedImage incomingImage;
    int inty;

    public PrintDocs(BufferedImage incomingImage) {
        this.incomingImage = incomingImage;
        inty = 0;

    }

    public void PrintImage() {
        HashPrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        attr.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0f, 0f, incomingImage.getWidth() / 72f, incomingImage.getHeight() / 72f,
                MediaPrintableArea.INCH));

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(this);
        PageFormat pf = job.pageDialog(job.defaultPage());
        boolean ok = job.printDialog();

        if (ok) {

            try {
                job.print(attr);
                inty = inty + 842;

            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                /* The job did not successfully complete */
            }

        }

    }

    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException {

        // if (page > 0){ //Use this for the moment may get rid of it
        // return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        // }

        /*
         * User (0,0 is typacally outside the imageable area, so we must
         * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormatz to avoid clipping
         */

        if (inty < incomingImage.getHeight()) {
            // if (inty < incomingImage.getHeight()){
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX() - 1.0, pf.getImageableY() - 1.0);

            /* Now we perform out rendering */

            g.drawImage(incomingImage, 0, 0, 595, 842, 0, inty, 595, 842 + inty, null);

            // g2d.drawImage(incomingImage, 0, 0, 595, 842, 0, inty, 595,842 +
            // inty, null);
            System.out.println("inty = " + inty);
            inty = inty + 842;
            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
}
```

Invoking printImage():

```
private void printActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){ 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //BufferedImage printCopy = tooOutput.displayProcessing.getCreatedImage();
    BufferedImage printCopy = tooOutput.getPrintImage();
    PrintDocs sendToPrinter = new PrintDocs(printCopy);
    sendToPrinter.PrintImage();
}
```

Comment: Can you show where you invoke the method `printImage()`.

Comment: Hint: **never** have empty catch clauses; at least do some logging; or print stack trace; so that when you are testing your stuff you are sure that you are not ignoring any exception. And **never** provide more information within comments. Update your question instead. And show some more respect: take your time to format your source code to be readable. You expect other people to spend their time to help you. So you spent some time making that as easy as possible.

Comment: You can actually just edit the question to put all the changes into it

Comment: @Gerry Yes, I was asking you too edit your current post by adding some codes, not via the comment. I added for you anyway. If it is inaccurate, you can edit it again.

Comment: Thank you I am always learning

Comment: @Gerry Take a look at my solution, let me know whether it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that inty is incremented each time the `print` method is called internally. That works iff the `print` method is called exactly once for each page.

From the JavaDoc of the `java.awt.print.Printable` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Printable.html):

> The printing system may request a page index more than once. On each occasion equal PageFormat parameters will be supplied.

Instead of counting the current page number itself, your print method should use a `page` parameter to determine which part of the image to print.

```
public class PrintDocs implements Printable {
    private static final int pageHeight = 842;
    private BufferedImage incomingImage;
    private int pagePrintCount = 0;

    public PrintDocs(BufferedImage incomingImage) {
        this.incomingImage = incomingImage;
    }

    public void PrintImage() {
        HashPrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        attr.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0f, 0f, incomingImage.getWidth() / 72f, incomingImage.getHeight() / 72f,
                MediaPrintableArea.INCH));

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(this);
        PageFormat pf = job.pageDialog(job.defaultPage());
        boolean ok = job.printDialog();

        if (ok) {

            try {
                job.print(attr);
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                System.out.println("The job did not successfully complete");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException {

        System.out.println("print called for page="+page+", call count="+pagePrintCount++);

        /*
         * User (0,0 is typacally outside the imageable area, so we must
         * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormatz to avoid clipping
         */

        if (page*pageHeight < incomingImage.getHeight()) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX() - 1.0, pf.getImageableY() - 1.0);

            /* Now we perform out rendering */

            g.drawImage(incomingImage, 0, 0, 595, pageHeight, 0, page*pageHeight, 595, pageHeight*(page+1), null);

            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `inty` seems to reset to because you always create a new instance of PrintDocs everytime your actionPerformed method is invoked.

```
PrintDocs sendToPrinter = new PrintDocs(printCopy); //This line causing the reset of inty
sendToPrinter.PrintImage();
```

To prevent that, you can keep a reference of the same PrintDocs instance:

```
private void printActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){ 
    BufferedImage printCopy = tooOutput.getPrintImage();
    sendToPrinter.PrintImage();  //Keep a reference of sendToPrinter in your class
}
```

---

An alternative solution will be making `intY` a staic variable and `printImage()` a static method. When you need to `print`, just invoke via the class name:

```
PrintDos.printImage();
```

And you class will look like:

```
public class PrintDocs implements Printable {
    static int inty = 0;    //<= become static 

    //other variables, methods and constructor not shown

    public static void PrintImage() {    //<= become static
        //implementation for printImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay I am still trying to get my head around it. If I make inty static how do I move down the buffered Image to print the whole document?

Comment: @Gerry What do mean by moving down the buffered Image?

Comment: My image is long and continuous. each time the loop operates inty changes value to give me my page size.

Comment: @Gerry Then you can try making only `intY` static and your `printImage()` method remain non static. Without knowing your complete code, I can only give your suggestions for you to try out.

Comment: i would not encourage you to make it static you don't know when other object is going to call your PrintDoc class and you end up with concurrency issues . You never know unless you are pretty sure